# Which pub sells which beer in the UK?

Tags: uk

Does anyone know of a reliable source of up to date data?

Especially for craft beers & real ale, rather than Fosters/Carlsberg, etc, although data on those is welcome too (and whisky, now that I come to think of it).

Comment: There are apps people use to rank and keep track of different beers they've tried, and where they had them.That would give you some information about what's served where. A couple of examples are Barly and Untappd (Barly has beer menus), but there may be others. Not sure how good the coverage is in the UK. You probably can't download their data, but you didn't say if you need that or if just viewing the data is good enough.

Comment: I want access to the data, as is usual on this site. I would like to incorporate it into an an app. Thanks (and upvote) for those.

Comment: Somewhat related : {British pubs & restaurants : opening times and location](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15888/british-pubs-restaurants-opening-times-and-location)

Answer (score 1):

CAMRA's [whatpub.com](https://whatpub.com/) / good beer guide [seems to have an API](https://gbg-api.camra.org.uk/), although you might have to become a member to access it

Looks like [someone has tried here](https://github.com/hazanjon/camra-pubs/blob/master/research/README.md), which might give you some leads

Comment: I see that you have commented on two of questions today (I can't remember if I linked them). So, welcome aboard. I fell sure that you will be a very valuable member of S.E. Upvotes all round :-) Thanx a 1,000,000