# British pubs & restaurants : opening times and location

Tags: uk, restaurant, location

Google maps shows nearby pubs  and restaurants. But it does not show if they are currently open, which is frustrating at some times of day.

If I google search for the establishment, they often have the opening hours.

I would like to create a mash up of these, but doubt that google would appreciate me scraping its data.

Is there any open database of British eating & drinking establishments with

- type of establishment
- location (either address, preferably with post code) or lat/long
- opening hours

Even if it is incomplete, my main aim is to say "if you walk there now, it will definitely be open".

Comment: In theory OSM https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours

Comment: Thanks for that! Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, OSM should store the data (although unlikely to be as actual as other non-open sources)

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Drestaurant

Bulk download: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/britain-and-ireland.html

[See here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12430/1511) for how to download bulk data and how to parse records to keep only certain keys/tags.