# Seeking live bar/ restauarant UK data API for ML application

Tags: data-request, api, scraping

Looking for an API I can use to create a bar/restaurant recommendation app in the UK, with the possibility of commercial use.

Will need to train a model on this data which may necessitate the "storing" or caching of the dataset.

Does anybody know of data I can legally use for this? Happy to pay for the use.

Comment: Possibly related : [British pubs & restaurants : opening times and location](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15888/british-pubs-restaurants-opening-times-and-location).